# Write output into a text file

Tags: go-ethereum, command-line

I am trying to write the output of a command of Geth into a text file.
Something like this in the case of Windows:

```
ipconfig /all > c:\my_directory\file_name.txt
```

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Directing the output of the geth command as such works

```
geth --verbosity 3 console > ~/output.text
```

The [verbosity for geth goes up to 5](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options), which might help in determining whether the output was just not being logged.

*Note: verbosity greater than 3 does log a lot of information that probably won't be relevant to you and might cause a lot of extra noise*

This resource might help https://askubuntu.com/a/731237 you with picking the desired syntax for directing the output.